# How to represent a min and max value of multiple categories in x axis as a candle stick plot in python. need to have unique colours for each category

Tags: charts, plotly, candlestick-chart

```
# Create a list of dictionaries representing each row of the data
data = [
    {"Team": "CHENNAI SUPER KINGS", "min": 1525, "max": 1625, "Is_awarded": "Yes"},
    {"Team": "LUCKNOW SUPER GIANTS", "min": 700, "max": 1600, "Is_awarded": None},
    {"Team": "RAJASTHAN ROYALS", "min": 200, "max": 725, "Is_awarded": None},
    {"Team": "ROYAL CHALLENGERS BANGALORE", "min": 220, "max": 650, "Is_awarded": None},
    {"Team": "SUNRISERS HYDERABAD", "min": 775, "max": 1475, "Is_awarded": None},
]

# Create the dataframe from the list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to plot a candle stick chart representing the team name in X axis and corresponding min max value. the colour of the candle stick should be unique with respect to the third column `Is_awarded`; if 'yes' then red & if 'NA' blue. is there a way?

I have tried plotly but I'm not able to colour code it.

Comment: i don't understand how you're intending to use a candlestick chart in this context. candlestick charts are usually for financial data, and the xaxis is almost always time. if you want the team name to be on the xaxis and bars from min-max values to be on the yaxis, then a bar chart with different colors for each bar would fit your use case much better. if you're interested in such a solution, i could write that up for you

Comment: yes derek please help me in this regard